# How can we get the result of swap in curve.fi like `getAmountsOut` for uniswapV2

Tags: uniswap, brownie, uniswapv3, curve, ape

I'm trying to get the price for the swap `WETH->DAI` by calling `get_dy` but there is no direct pool in `curve`. I went to the UI & put in this swap & got this. tricypto: `WETH -> USDT -> USDT -> DAI`. How can we simulate this, when there is no direct pool?
This is my current code

```py
def CurveSwapIn(pool, _from: str, tokenIn: str, tokenout: str, amount: int = 0) -> int:

    i = 0
    j = 0
    coinIdx = 0

    while i == j:
        coin = pool.coins.call(coinIdx, sender=_from)

        if coin == tokenIn:
            i = coinIdx
        elif coin == tokenOut:
            j = coinIdx

        if i != j:
            break

        coinIdx += 1

    amountsOut = pool.get_dy.call(i, j, amount, sender=_from)

    return amountsOut
```

- Calling params

```json
Calling CurveSwapIn with params: 
{'pool': <ICurvePool 0x90E00ACe148ca3b23Ac1bC8C240C2a7Dd9c2d7f5>, 
'_from': <TestAccount 0xFe498FB74efa3D66A3744011b7577F876cf61Dd0>, 
'tokenIn': '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2', 
'tokenout': '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F', 
'amount': 1000000000000000000}
```

- I'm using `ape` & tired in `brownie` as well. Getting this error `ERROR: (ContractLogicError) Transaction failed.` at `coin = pool.coins.call(coinIdx, sender=_from)`